# Placing label over mapped 3D graph in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want the below desired effect

[image: Desired image]

I am using a gnuplot script *similar* to this

```
reset
set term postscript eps enhanced "Helvetica" 30
set size square
set xlabel "X position"
set ylabel "Y position"
set pm3d map
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
set xrange [0 : 22.0000000000]
set yrange [0 : 17.0000000000]
set zrange [0 : 0.1614027105]
set xtics 5
set ytics 0,4
set cbtics 0,0.020
set style line 1 lw 1
unset key
set dgrid3d 45,45
set style line 1 lt 1
set hidden3d
splot "data.data" u 1:2:3
set label "98.8" at 9,-2 textcolor lt 1
set label "1.2" at 9,6 textcolor lt 1
```

But when I do, the labels (`98.8`, and `1.2`) don't get printed. If I provide a bogus `data.data` file, lets say with only a single `(x,y,z)` point, then nothing gets graphed and I can see the labels. Therefore, I am guessing that my graph is occluding my labels. How do I get the labels to be printed on top of my graph?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default placement for labels is in back.
But you can specify that the label show up in front, e.g.:

```
set label "label in front" at 2.5,0.5 tc rgb "white" font ",30" front
```

Credit: the (very slightly modified) code for this was found at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_4.5/pm3dcolors.html and/or link(s) therefrom.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also for further information on the placement of text in gnuplot, I found [this reference](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?%28gnuplot%29label) to be very useful.

Comment: That web page has a `File IO Error
The Info file could not be opened for reading.` :-(